# Animation Nodes : How to access object properties in the 3D viewport

Tags: animation-nodes, transform-orientation

I require some help please. Blender 2.8 Animation Node Addon. I am using the "Object Transforms Output". Here I can rotate and move objects, but in the 3d viewport I cannot do anything.
I would like to do both. Use the Node and also move the object in the 3d viewport and update the node automatically.
It needs to be the same as using the transforms in the property panel.
My goal is to have all objects listed with each of their transforms. Can this be done? Thanks in advance, if anyone can help.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. You can't do both, you can either set their transforms or edit it.

Comment: I'm searching a way to have a transform panel for each of my objects visible in a separate window. These are always visible whether the objects are selected or not. Ideally placed below the timeline.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles next time. And structure your question into multiple paragraphs describing the problem, what you want to create, and what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ID panel to create ID Transformation Keys to objects and set those ID Transformations in your node tree as follows:

[image: Node Tree]